# do I need to push all react and node files to Heroku local repository or just the build folder?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I'm new to react and node and I'm trying to push my first app to Heroku. I'm following this guide: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/

it says to login to Heroku, create a local git repo and push all the files. I did all the steps except pushing the files because it's not really clear if I'm supposed to push all the source files or just the build folder that is created when running `npm build`.

also my Heroku folder (where I created the local repo) is in a separate folder than all the react app and the node server folders because I already have a git repo on that folder.

Comment: heroku will build the files; push all your files except node modules

Comment: so do I need to copy all the files except the node modules to the Heroku folder? or can I have two repos on the same folder?

Comment: I suppose you can connect that to your git repo directly here you can also take ref from :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-deploy-react-app-to-heroku/

Comment: thank you! there is a section there talking about existing apps and it's exactly what I was looking for